# Gradle: unable to resolve imported task from a non build.gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a `docs.gradle` file with

```
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.dokka"

import org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaTask
....
```

and I apply it from my module level build.gradle file

```
apply from: '../gradle/docs.gradle'
```

But I get

```
Could not compile script ...
script <path to docs.gradle> : 3: unable to resolve class org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaTask
```

import line is accepted if placed in any `build.gradle` file (root or module level)
Exception:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.groovy.scripts.ScriptCompilationException: Could not compile script '..../gradle/docs.gradle'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.wrapCompilationFailure(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:192)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileScript(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:141)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileToDir(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:95)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler$2.run(BuildOperationBackedScriptCompilationHandler.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
```

Answer (score 4):

Gradle plugins can be applied in two ways: using the recommended [plugins DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block) (using `plugins { ... }` block) or the [legacy plugins application](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:old_plugin_application) way (using  `buildscript { ...}` with `apply plugin: "$pluginId"`)

But Plugins DSL is not available in scripts plugins (see [plugins dsl limitations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:build_scripts_only)) so you need to use the legacy plugin application syntax.

So you should just have to add the missing `buildscript` block into your `docs.gradle` script, to provide Gradle a way to resolve the "org.jetbrains.dokka" plugin which is not a Gradle core plugin:

*docs.gradle*

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:1.6.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.dokka"
    
import org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaTask

// ...
```

Unfortunately there is this known issue [#1262 - Third-party plugins cannot be applied by ID from external build scripts](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1262) ..

A workaround is to apply plugin by its implementation class, not by its ID (see [this comment](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1262#issuecomment-382471017)), as follows

*docs.gradle*

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            gradlePluginPortal()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:1.6.0"
        }
    }
    
    // apply plugin:  'org.jetbrains.dokka' <-- apply by ID not supported here.
    apply plugin : org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaPlugin   // <-- this works fine
    
    import org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaTask
```